# Prestashop CSV Import on Localhost

Tags: import, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Setup:
- Prestashop 1.6 Fresh Install
- Products CSV export from a live site (Prestashop 1.4)

Goal:
What I want to accomplish is to completely test the CSV Import on localhost first 
before doing it on a new site. I have already tried it on the live site and I encounter
a bunch of errors, so I though it would be better to test is first.

Problem:
Now the problem is that the CSV Import doesnt seem to work on localost. Whenever I try to upload the CSV i get a "products_stream.csv (382.23 KB) : File is too large" error.

I have also tried copying the csv file directly to the admin/import folder to see if it would appear on the 'Choose from history /FTP' list but that also failed.

Would greatly appreciate any help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

it depends on PHP configuration variables.  Edit your php.ini file and increase these values, for localhost develop you can do it without fear.

Example PHP.ini modifications

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; Modified for prestashop develop 
upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

I also suggest you to change these other values in order to better Prestashop develop:

```
memory_limit = 512M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
max_input_vars = 5000    ; Numero maximo de variables post
```

After changing values, don't forget to restart your LAMP or WAMP server (almost Apache) and to clear browser cookies before retrying import process.

Best regards